# Speedup extracting data form larger xml files using python

Tags: python, xml, anaconda, lxml

Hello I am not strong python user , but need to extract the xml file values.

I am using for loop to get attribute values from 'xml.dom.minidom.document'
Both the xyz or temp uses for loop , since the file has half million values it takes time.
I tried using lxml, but it had error:
module 'lxml' has no attribute 'parse' or 'Xpath'

The xml file has following format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<variable_output>
  <!--version      : 1-->
  <!--object title : Volume (1)-->
  <!--scalar variable : Temperature (TEMP)-->
  <POINT>
    <Vertex>
      <Position x="-0.176300004" y="-0.103100002" z="-0.153699994"/>
      <Scalar TEMP="84.192421"/>
    </Vertex>
  </POINT>
  <POINT>
    <Vertex>
      <Position x="-0.173557162" y="-0.103100002" z="-0.153699994"/>
      <Scalar TEMP="83.9050522"/>
    </Vertex>
  </POINT>
  <POINT>
    <Vertex>
      <Position x="-0.170814306" y="-0.103100002" z="-0.153699994"/>
      <Scalar TEMP="83.7506332"/>
    </Vertex>
  </POINT>
</variable_output>
```

The following code give larger time for bigger files.

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
import time
from lxml import etree

v=[]

doc =parse("document.xml")
Val = doc.getElementsByTagName("Scalar")

        

t0 = time.time()
for s in Val:
    v=np.append(v,float(s.attributes['TEMP'].value))
res=np.array([v])
t1 = time.time()
total = (t1-t0)
print('Time for Value', str(total))

# Using lxml 
doc2=etree.parse("document.xml")
        
# try using Xpath
t0 = time.time()
temp=doc2.Xpath("/POINT/Vertex/Scaler/@TEMP")
t1 = time.time()
total2 = t1-t0
print('Time for Value', str(total2))

# save data as csv from xml
pd.DataFrame(res.T).to_csv(('Data.csv'),index=False,header=False)   #write timestep as csv
```

The error while using the Xpath to get the values of Temp,or x,y,z:

```
In [12]: temp=doc2.Xpath("/POINT/Vertex/Scaler/@TEMP")
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-12-bbd832a3074e>", line 1, in <module>
    temp=doc2.Xpath("/POINT/Vertex/Scaler/@TEMP")

AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'Xpath'
```

Comment: Questions should provide a [mcve], XML sample is not well formed and some var definition are missing.

Comment: I am sorry for the difficulty due to incomplete data before. I updated both code and data- document

Comment: You seem to be using both minidom and lxml in the same script. It is confusing.

Comment: `import lxml as etree` does not work. It should be `from lxml import etree`.

Comment: Hello, I tried using the from lxml import etree, but the it donot show Xpath

Comment: The method is called `xpath` (all lower case letters). https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#xpath

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `iterparse()` for large xml files:

```
import timeit
import os, psutil
import datetime

import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class parse_xml:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.xml = os.path.split(path)[1]
        print(self.xml)
        
        columns = ["Pos_x", "Pos_y", "Pos_z", "Scalar_Temp"]
        
        data = []
        for event, elem in ET.iterparse(self.xml, events=("end",)):
            if elem.tag == "Position":
                x = elem.get("x")
                y = elem.get("y")
                z = elem.get("z")
            if elem.tag == "Scalar":
                row = (x, y, z , elem.get("TEMP"))
                data.append(row)
            elem.clear()
                       
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
        print(df)
    
def main():
    xml_file = r"D:\Daten\Programmieren\stackoverflow\document.xml"
    parse_xml(xml_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    starttime = timeit.default_timer()
    main()
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print('\nFinished')
    print(f"{now:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M}")
    print('Runtime:', timeit.default_timer()-starttime)
    print(f'RAM: {process.memory_info().rss/1000**2} MB')
```

Output:

```
document.xml
          Pos_x         Pos_y         Pos_z Scalar_Temp
0  -0.176300004  -0.103100002  -0.153699994   84.192421
1  -0.173557162  -0.103100002  -0.153699994  83.9050522
2  -0.170814306  -0.103100002  -0.153699994  83.7506332

Finished
2022-11-29 23:51
Runtime: 0.007375300000000029
RAM: 55.619584 MB
```

If the output will be too large you can write it to a sqlite3 database with `df.to_sql()`.